# Save Form Data to Database through Ajax Call in Colorbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, colorbox

I have placed a form in the Colorbox and want to Save the form contents in the Database. But when i Click on Submit button the Colorbox closes and the action is not completed .

Need some guideline on this.Thanks

```
$("img").colorbox({opacity:0.3,top:100,width:"800px",height:"500px", href:"editquote.php?id="+eid+""});
```

-------------editquote.php -->

```
<form method="POST" id="editform" action=""><table>
<tr><td><textarea name="quote" style="width:390px;" value="<?php echo $edit_quoteid;?>"><?php echo $quote;?></textarea></td></tr>
<input type="submit" value="Save" name="Save">
</table>     </form>
<?php
$edit_quoteid=$_GET['id'];
if(isset($_POST['Save'])){       
$qcontent=$_POST['quote'];
$up_query="UPDATE daily_quotes SET quote='".$qcontent."',WHERE id=".$edit_quoteid;
$edit_quote=mysql_query($up_query) or die();
?>
```

----->Ajax call wriiten on editquote.php page

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit_editquote").off("click").on("click",function(){
            var data = $("form#editform").find("input").serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    url:'./index.php',
                    data:data,
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also i changed the "submit" button to "button" and  submit_editquote is its id given

Comment: paste your code, my magic wand is broken mate else i would have sorted your code magically

Comment: @noobie-php - plz check the code and provide guidelines

Comment: you have syntax error in code 1st sort that out and then tell me what you are getting , your error for now is that you are not closing the IF condition in the above mentioned code.

Comment: @noobie-php  --IF is properly closed in my application ..not an issue there

Comment: More over tour code is also in complete i dont know from where are you getting/using `$quote` and `$edit_quoteid`

Comment: @noobie-php  --Colorbox is on other page and from there i am calling this page

Comment: i am not talking about application mate, i am talking about the above code its either incomplete or what i said is correct

Comment: I can see what you are doing you are passing ID from some other page to editQuote page, but i cannot help till i know whole scenario

Comment: @noobie-php   consider the first page as "index.php" .. in ths page i am loading "Colorbox"(as shown in 1st part) when i click on image icon ..'eid' is the id of the image..with the info coming from 'id' .. i am displaying a form(second page code) which firstly shows all the details in input fields and then hav a 'save' button which on clicking should save the edited inputs to database... but when i click on the button the colorbox gets closed

Comment: colorbox will close as you are redirecting to same page i.e your complete page is loading again, so previous values/attrs that you are fetching from other page will remove, and only thing that you will get in your scenario are your 2nd page attr/values, if you dont want older things on page try AJAX or by some way save them in your 2nd page and re-render them

Comment: @noobie-php -- hav a look at ajax call

Comment: first on click the ajax request and after success colorbox.close event close it may be work

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to respond some thing in order to check ajax request response;

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    $edit_quoteid = $_GET['id'];
    if(isset($_POST['Save'])){  
        $edit_quoteid = $_POST['id'];
        $qcontent = $_POST['quote'];
        $up_query = "UPDATE daily_quotes SET quote='" . $qcontent . "',WHERE id=" . $edit_quoteid;
        $edit_quote=mysql_query($up_query);
        echo $edit_quote; // This will be false on qquery failure else true
    }
?>
```

**HTML:** Put hidden element for sending id

```
<form method="POST" id="editform" action="">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><textarea name="quote" style="width:390px;" value="<?php echo $edit_quoteid;?>"><?php echo $quote;?></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']" name="edit_quoteid">
        <input type="button" value="Save" name="Save" id="submit_editquote">
    </table>
</form>
```

**JS:** Check response and decide if you close fancybox or not

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit_editquote").on("click",function(){
            var data = $("form#editform").serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    url:'./index.php',
                    data:data,
                    success: function(response) {
                        if (response) {
                            alert("Success");
                            //Close fancybox here
                        } else {
                            alert("Update operation failed");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(xhr.status);
                        alert(thrownError);
                    }
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```